# Enter Key Event on CheckBox in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am novice in jquery implementation.. I need to apply enter key event on checkbox with **id="mycheckbox"** so that whenever i press enter key on checkbox it should be selected. What i have tried so far is below, but it seems not working.
Any suggestion is greatly appriciated.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input:checkbox[id=mycheckbox]').keypress(function(event) {
                var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                alert('keycode='+keycode+' pressed.');
                if (keycode == 13) {
                    clickCheckBox(this);
                }   
                event.stopPropagation();
            });

            $('input:checkbox[id=mycheckbox]').click(function(){
                clickCheckBox(this);
            });
        });

        function clickCheckBox(box){

                var $box = $(box);
                if($box.attr('checked'))
                    $box.attr('checked',false);
                else
                    $box.attr('checked',true);

        }
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle link.

Comment: you can shorten `input:checkbox[id=mycheckbox]` into `#mycheckbox`

Comment: Seem to work just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/gvy4rzzd/

Comment: @adeneo pressing the enter-button again will not checking the `checkbox`, I think that is the problem here

Comment: Please keep in mind: ID's (#) should be unique! Don't use the same ID on multiple elements! (I assume you use the id on multiple checkboxes)

Comment: @empiric - you're right, that's because `attr` is the wrong method, it should be `prop`

Comment: It should look like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/gvy4rzzd/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you for useful comments and answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removed click event(you don't need it) and modified code little bit(used prop instead of attr)..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#mycheckbox').keypress(function(event) {
         var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

         if (keycode == 13) {
             clickCheckBox(this);
         }
         event.stopPropagation();
     });
 });

 function clickCheckBox(box) {

     var $box = $(box);
     $box.prop('checked', !$box.prop('checked'));

 }
```

created jsfiddle for this and working fine..

http://jsfiddle.net/c2S5d/23/

Answer (score 3):

If i understand your requirement correctly pls check this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:checkbox[id=mycheckbox]').keypress(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var keycode = getKeyCodeFromEvent(event);
        if (keycode == 13) {
            clickCheckBox(this);
        }
    });
});

function clickCheckBox(box) {
   $(box).trigger('click');
}
function getKeyCodeFromEvent(event) {
   return (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
}
```

Comment: this disables the ability to check the `checkbox` via click due to `trigger('click')`. have a closer look at your code ;-)

Comment: yes it doesnt require click function updated it @empiric

Comment: seems correct one but stop propagation need to be inside keycode checking, `if (keycode == 13) {  clickCheckBox(this); event.stopPropagation(); }`. Otherwise no other key like tabkey will work.

Comment: @HussainKMRBehestee Thanks Updated

Answer (score 2):

This code works, tested on Chrome 30

```
<html>
<body>
<input type='checkbox' id='mycheckbox' />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mycheckbox').keydown(function(ev){
      if(ev.keyCode == 13) $(ev.target).click(); 
    })
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gvy4rzzd/1/):

There is a problem in your code here

```
  function clickCheckBox(box){

            var $box = $(box);
            if($box.attr('checked'))
                $box.attr('checked',false);
            else
                $box.attr('checked',true);

    }
```

`.attr()` doesn't accepts boolean values . Go for `prop()` if you are using jQuery 1.6 or above that

Answer (score 1):

I had needed same thing in Angulajs and found a solution. Thinking that it might help others as there no other question was raised for Angular I am sharing my code here:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('input', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', // Only search input element
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      if (attr.type === 'checkbox') { //filtered out the checkbox only
        elm.on('keypress', function(event){
         if(event.keyCode === 13){
           event.preventDefault();
           elm.trigger('click');
           scope.$apply();
         }
       });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

hope it will help you those who are seeking for the same solution in AngularJS...